# Apart from maps and vectors are there any other uses of get in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure, get

The uses that I know so far are on vectors:

```
(get [1 2 3 4] 2) ; => 3
```

and on maps:

```
(get {:a "a" :b "B" :c "c"} :c) ; => "c"
```

From documentation it says:

> clojure.core/get ([map key] [map key not-found])
>
> Returns the value mapped to key, not-found or nil if key not present.

Answer (score 9):

Apart from maps and vectors, a common use for *get* is on strings:

```
(get "Cthulhu" 2) ;; => \h
```

*get* also works on sets and native Java(Script) arrays. One possible use in ClojureScript and JavaScript inter-op:

```
(def js-array (-> (js/Array 10) ;Create and fill native JS array
                  (.fill "a")
                  (.map (fn [_ i] i))))
(get js-array 3) ; => 3
```

As another example, get works for looking up by item in a set:

```
(get #{:b :c :a} :c) ;;=> :c
```

Note that it does not work with a (sorted) set and index, for example:

```
(get (sorted-set :b :a :c) 1) ;; throws exception
```

Further, maps, vectors, and sets act as functions of their members, so you can often avoid using *get* altogether:

```
(#{:a :b :c} :b) ; => :b
({:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} :b) ; => 2
([:a :b :c] 1) ; => :b
```

The advantage of using *get* with them is that you can provide a default value:

```
(get {:a :b :c} :d) ; => nil
(get {:a :b :c} :d :not-found) ; => :not-found
```

See also [@Thumbnail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994592/8123584) to understand how *get* works under the hood.

Comment: Notice, that for maps you can use `(({:a 1 :b 2} :c 10)` to specify default value. It doesn't work for vectors, however

Answer (score 3):

Further to [@ToniVanhanla's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44983770/1562315), for the JVM, the relevant Clojure interface is `clojure.lang.ILookup`.

Looking, as the Americans say, under the hood,

- Clojure `get` translates into a call to `clojure.lang.RT/get`.
- If possible, this casts to `ILookup` and calls the appropriate
  `valAt` method.
- If not, it calls `...RT/getFrom`
- ... whose clauses deal explicitly with, in turn,

  - Java maps,
  - Clojure sets, and
  - Java strings and arrays.

If none of these fits, it returns `nil`.

There is no parent interface for Java arrays: they all descend directly from `Object`. They are detected by Java's `Class/isArray`

---

Somewhat surprisingly, Clojure `get` does not work on Java collections such as `Vector`s:

```
(java.util.Vector. (seq "Hello, world!"))
=> [\H \e \l \l \o \, \space \w \o \r \l \d \!]
```

But

```
(get (java.util.Vector. (seq "Hello, world!")) 4)
=> nil
```